# Как запустить функцию другого модуля в новом процессе

Tags: python, aiogram, asyncio, multiprocessing

Возникла проблема с асинхронностью кода на python. У нас есть бот, написанный на библиотеке **aiogram**. В нем необходимо создать процесс, в котором будет бесконечно выполнятся функция из другого модуля. Как это реализовать?

Вот код функции из другого модуля (parser), который нужно запустить в новом процессе:

```
async def main():
    while True:
        tasks = [
            asyncio.create_task(parse_skysports()),
            asyncio.create_task(parse_guardiansport()),
            asyncio.create_task(parse_ign()),
            asyncio.create_task(parse_stopgame()),
            asyncio.create_task(parse_politico()),
            asyncio.create_task(parse_voanews())
        ]

        connection = db.DbConnection()

        for result in await asyncio.gather(*tasks):
            connection.update_data(paper_name=result[0], news=result[1])

        time.sleep(20)
```

Эту функцию необходимо вызвать через **asyncio.run()** в основном модуле, но так, чтобы бот продолжал работать.

Вот такой подход не работал:

```
import parser
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import multiprocessing as mp
...

def parsing():
    asyncio.run(parser.main())
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
    process = mp.Process(target=parsing)
    process.start()
```

В данном случае бот работал, но функция из модуля **parser** не работала.

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: я так понимаю у вас общая база для бота и парсера?

Comment: @СергейШ Верно.

Comment: по логике сначала создаем процесс и запускаем, а потом запускаем бота..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно создать два процесса - с ботом и с `while True: ...`

```
def parsing():
  asyncio.run(parser.main())
def start_bot():
  executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

и запустить два процесса:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

  bot_process = mp.Process(target=start_bot)
  parser_process = mp.Process(target=parsing)
 
  bot_process.join()
  parser_process.join()
```

Comment: Все работает, если join() поменять на start()